# TensorFlow Object Detection API ERROR - Access Denied [WINDOWS]

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am experiencing somewhat strange error when trying to run TF Object Detection API on my Windows machine. I've followed instructions from this link: https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html and when I try to execute this command:

```
(tensorflow) C:\AI\workspace\lesion-detector>python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models\efficientdet_d7_coco17_tpu-32 --pipeline_config_path=models\efficientdet_d7_coco17_tpu-32\pipeline.config
```

I continue running into following error that seems admin related:

```
2020-12-17 00:42:38.965732: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-12-17 00:42:38.969554: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2020-12-17 00:42:45.426696: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2020-12-17 00:42:45.431948: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:312] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-12-17 00:42:45.494938: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: LAPTOP-OV90Q43O
2020-12-17 00:42:45.497657: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: LAPTOP-OV90Q43O
2020-12-17 00:42:45.519882: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-12-17 00:42:45.615056: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x255d421a660 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-12-17 00:42:45.617908: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
WARNING:tensorflow:There are non-GPU devices in `tf.distribute.Strategy`, not using nccl allreduce.
W1217 00:42:45.627968 28372 cross_device_ops.py:1202] There are non-GPU devices in `tf.distribute.Strategy`, not using nccl allreduce.
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',)
I1217 00:42:45.628966 28372 mirrored_strategy.py:341] Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',)
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting train_steps: None
I1217 00:42:45.641946 28372 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting train_steps: None
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
I1217 00:42:45.643917 28372 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
I1217 00:42:45.667483 28372 ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py:143] EfficientDet EfficientNet backbone version: efficientnet-b6
I1217 00:42:45.667483 28372 ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py:145] EfficientDet BiFPN num filters: 384
I1217 00:42:45.672475 28372 ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py:146] EfficientDet BiFPN num iterations: 8
I1217 00:42:45.683438 28372 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=32 output=56
I1217 00:42:45.761782 28372 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=32 output=56
I1217 00:42:45.761782 28372 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=16 output=32
I1217 00:42:46.130767 28372 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=16 output=32
I1217 00:42:46.130767 28372 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=24 output=40
I1217 00:42:47.210981 28372 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=24 output=40
I1217 00:42:47.220941 28372 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=40 output=72
I1217 00:42:48.230952 28372 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=40 output=72
I1217 00:42:48.230952 28372 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=80 output=144
I1217 00:42:49.730924 28372 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=80 output=144
I1217 00:42:49.730924 28372 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=112 output=200
I1217 00:42:51.552680 28372 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=112 output=200
I1217 00:42:51.552680 28372 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=192 output=344
I1217 00:42:53.770886 28372 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=192 output=344
I1217 00:42:53.770886 28372 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=320 output=576
I1217 00:42:54.440793 28372 efficientnet_model.py:148] round_filter input=1280 output=2304
I1217 00:42:54.546431 28372 efficientnet_model.py:460] Building model efficientnet with params ModelConfig(width_coefficient=1.8, depth_coefficient=2.6, resolution=528, dropout_rate=0.5, blocks=(BlockConfig(input_filters=32, output_filters=16, kernel_size=3, num_repeat=1, expand_ratio=1, strides=(1, 1), se_ratio=0.25, id_skip=True, fused_conv=False, conv_type='depthwise'), BlockConfig(input_filters=16, output_filters=24, kernel_size=3, num_repeat=2, expand_ratio=6, strides=(2, 2), se_ratio=0.25, id_skip=True, fused_conv=False, conv_type='depthwise'), BlockConfig(input_filters=24, output_filters=40, kernel_size=5, num_repeat=2, expand_ratio=6, strides=(2, 2), se_ratio=0.25, id_skip=True, fused_conv=False, conv_type='depthwise'), BlockConfig(input_filters=40, output_filters=80, kernel_size=3, num_repeat=3, expand_ratio=6, strides=(2, 2), se_ratio=0.25, id_skip=True, fused_conv=False, conv_type='depthwise'), BlockConfig(input_filters=80, output_filters=112, kernel_size=5, num_repeat=3, expand_ratio=6, strides=(1, 1), se_ratio=0.25, id_skip=True, fused_conv=False, conv_type='depthwise'), BlockConfig(input_filters=112, output_filters=192, kernel_size=5, num_repeat=4, expand_ratio=6, strides=(2, 2), se_ratio=0.25, id_skip=True, fused_conv=False, conv_type='depthwise'), BlockConfig(input_filters=192, output_filters=320, kernel_size=3, num_repeat=1, expand_ratio=6, strides=(1, 1), se_ratio=0.25, id_skip=True, fused_conv=False, conv_type='depthwise')), stem_base_filters=32, top_base_filters=1280, activation='simple_swish', batch_norm='default', bn_momentum=0.99, bn_epsilon=0.001, weight_decay=5e-06, drop_connect_rate=0.2, depth_divisor=8, min_depth=None, use_se=True, input_channels=3, num_classes=1000, model_name='efficientnet', rescale_input=False, data_format='channels_last', dtype='float32')
INFO:tensorflow:Reading unweighted datasets: ['annotations/train.tfrecord']
I1217 00:42:54.866364 28372 dataset_builder.py:148] Reading unweighted datasets: ['annotations/train.tfrecord']
INFO:tensorflow:Reading record datasets for input file: ['annotations/train.tfrecord']
I1217 00:42:54.871346 28372 dataset_builder.py:77] Reading record datasets for input file: ['annotations/train.tfrecord']
INFO:tensorflow:Number of filenames to read: 1
I1217 00:42:54.872344 28372 dataset_builder.py:78] Number of filenames to read: 1
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
W1217 00:42:54.873340 28372 dataset_builder.py:85] num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:99: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_deterministic`.
W1217 00:42:54.879320 28372 deprecation.py:317] From C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:99: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_deterministic`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:221: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
W1217 00:42:54.924170 28372 deprecation.py:317] From C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:221: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
W1217 00:43:00.370958 28372 deprecation.py:317] From C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\inputs.py:281: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
W1217 00:43:04.100594 28372 deprecation.py:317] From C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\inputs.py:281: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:UnknownError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: models\efficientdet_d7_coco17_tpu-32\checkpoint : Access is denied.
; Input/output error
W1217 00:43:06.330821 28372 checkpoint_management.py:295] UnknownError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: models\efficientdet_d7_coco17_tpu-32\checkpoint : Access is denied.
; Input/output error
WARNING:tensorflow:models\efficientdet_d7_coco17_tpu-32\checkpoint: Checkpoint ignored
W1217 00:43:06.330821 28372 checkpoint_management.py:296] models\efficientdet_d7_coco17_tpu-32\checkpoint: Checkpoint ignored
WARNING:tensorflow:UnknownError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: models\efficientdet_d7_coco17_tpu-32\checkpoint : Access is denied.
; Input/output error
W1217 00:43:06.338711 28372 checkpoint_management.py:295] UnknownError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: models\efficientdet_d7_coco17_tpu-32\checkpoint : Access is denied.
; Input/output error
WARNING:tensorflow:models\efficientdet_d7_coco17_tpu-32\checkpoint: Checkpoint ignored
W1217 00:43:06.338711 28372 checkpoint_management.py:296] models\efficientdet_d7_coco17_tpu-32\checkpoint: Checkpoint ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 113, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 104, in main
    model_lib_v2.train_loop(
  File "C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 627, in train_loop
    manager.save()
  File "C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\checkpoint_management.py", line 819, in save
    self._record_state()
  File "C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\checkpoint_management.py", line 722, in _record_state
    update_checkpoint_state_internal(
  File "C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\checkpoint_management.py", line 247, in update_checkpoint_state_internal
    file_io.atomic_write_string_to_file(coord_checkpoint_filename,
  File "C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 570, in atomic_write_string_to_file
    rename(temp_pathname, filename, overwrite)
  File "C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 529, in rename
    rename_v2(oldname, newname, overwrite)
  File "C:\Users\stefa\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 545, in rename_v2
    _pywrap_file_io.RenameFile(
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Failed to rename: models\efficientdet_d7_coco17_tpu-32\checkpoint.tmpceeed88cbf1642a4bd42df0a819bc144 to: models\efficientdet_d7_coco17_tpu-32\checkpoint : Access is denied.
; Input/output error
```

Bare in mind that:

- I am using Anaconda
- I've got Python in my PATH environment variable
- I've opened Anaconda Prompt as an administrator

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try the steps mentioned https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md